# How i can make tables for the given many to many related classes?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a scenario of of three classes .I am planning to make the database for it .The relationship between them is :

- 1 customer is related with many items and many dv-vouchers.
- 1 item is related with many customer and many dv-vouchers.
- 1 dv-vouchers is related with 1 customer and many items .

> ```
> public Customer
>  {
>    int cust_id;
>    list<items> items;
>    list<dvouchers> dvouchers;
>  }
> public items
>  {
>    int itm_id;
>    list<Customer>  customers;
>    list<dvouchers>  dvouchers;
>  }
> public dvouchers
>  {
>    int dv_id;
>    Customer customer;
>    list<items> items;
>  }
> ```

First of all what can be the design for database tables for above classes, fk_constraints and relationship tables ?

Second Do I need to perform Insert and Update operation on both the relationship tables along db table ? Please Help .

Answer (score 1):

1.
You need two tables **Customer_Item** and **Item_Dvoucher** for relationship *many-to-many* and field **cust_id** in table **Dvoucher** for *one-to-one* relationship.

2.
You need to insert or update data in base tables **Customer**, **Item** and **Dvoucher**. Then you need to add or remove relationship in table **Customer_Item** and **Items_Dvoucher**. Also fill field **cust_id** in table **Dvoucher**.

Generated in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `cust_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cust_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Dvoucher` (
  `dv_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dv_id`),
  KEY `cust_id` (`cust_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Dvoucher_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cust_id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`cust_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Item` (
  `item_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Customer_Item` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cust_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cust_id` (`cust_id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_Item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cust_id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`cust_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_Item_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `Item` (`item_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Item_Dvoucher` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dv_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `dv_id` (`dv_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Item_Dvoucher_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `Item` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Item_Dvoucher_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dv_id`) REFERENCES `Dvoucher` (`dv_id`)
)
```

Comment: answered in item 2 in my answer

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(cust_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...);
CREATE TABLE item(itm_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...);
CREATE TABLE dvoucher(dv_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cust_id REFERENCES customer(cust_id), ...);
CREATE TABLE dvoucher_item(dv_id REFERENCES dvoucher(dv_id), itm_id REFERENCES item(itm_id));
CREATE TABLE customer_item(cust_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, itm_id REFERENCES item(itm_id));
```

As @Andrei solution to MySQL, using `dvoucher.cust_id` to link `dvoucher` to `costumer`, and tables `dvoucher_item` and `customer_item` to many to many links.